# How to optimize this sql in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query operation as below, it is from a single table but too much sub-query. Anybody could optimizing on it?

```
 SELECT t.order_no         ,
  user_assign             ,
  t.busi_code             ,
  t.inst_addr4 AS district,
  t.inst_addr3 AS estate  
 ,listagg(to_char(date_appoint,'yyyy-mm-dd'),',') within group(order by date_appoint asc) as "日期排序"
   FROM mtce_detail t
  WHERE order_no IN
  (SELECT order_no
     FROM
    (SELECT m.order_no,
      user_assign    ,
      COUNT(order_no) AS total
       FROM mtce_detail m
      WHERE order_no IN
      (SELECT order_no
         FROM mtce_detail
        WHERE date_appoint = to_date('2014-04-17', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
      )
    AND date_appoint <= to_date('2014-04-17', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
   GROUP BY order_no,
      user_assign
    )
    WHERE total > 2
  )
  group by t.order_no,t.user_assign,t.busi_code,t.inst_addr4,t.inst_addr3
```

Comment: What is the problem? Too slow? If so, please post an execution plan.

Comment: Optimising sometimes involves splitting a query into multiple sub-queries which can be executed in parallel, so hving sub-queries is not of itself a bad thing. As @Thilo says: what's the problem? Is it slow?

Comment: No problem with it. I just want to konw is there any way to optimize it and keep it more butiful. I think it is too clumsiness, just so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step you can take, is to remove the subquery with the "total > 2", and replace that with the more elegant HAVING clause, like this:

```
SELECT t.order_no
     , user_assign
     , t.busi_code
     , t.inst_addr4 AS district
     , t.inst_addr3 AS estate  
     , listagg(to_char(date_appoint,'yyyy-mm-dd'),',') within group(order by date_appoint asc) as "something_chinese"
  FROM mtce_detail t
 WHERE order_no IN
       ( SELECT m.order_no
           FROM mtce_detail m
          WHERE order_no IN
                ( SELECT order_no
                    FROM mtce_detail
                   WHERE date_appoint = to_date('2014-04-17', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
                )
            AND date_appoint <= to_date('2014-04-17', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
          GROUP BY order_no
              , user_assign
         having count(order_no) > 2
       )
 group by t.order_no
     , t.user_assign
     , t.busi_code
     , t.inst_addr4
     , t.inst_addr3
```

The next step is to eliminate a table access by removing the innermost subquery. Just select all mtce_details on or before 17th April 2014 and count the number of occurrences on that day and before, in one shot. Now you can use those calculated number in the having clause, like this:

```
SELECT t.order_no
     , user_assign
     , t.busi_code
     , t.inst_addr4 AS district
     , t.inst_addr3 AS estate  
     , listagg(to_char(date_appoint,'yyyy-mm-dd'),',') within group (order by date_appoint asc) as "something_chinese"
  FROM mtce_detail t
 WHERE order_no IN
       ( SELECT m.order_no
           FROM mtce_detail m
          WHERE date_appoint <= date '2014-04-17'
          GROUP BY order_no
              , user_assign
         having count(order_no) > 2
            and count(case date_appoint when date '2014-04-17' then 1 end) >= 1
       )
 group by t.order_no
     , t.user_assign
     , t.busi_code
     , t.inst_addr4
     , t.inst_addr3
```

Performance should have improved slightly, but your query still contains two table accesses of the same table. If you need the last table access out, you can use analytic functions with the partition clause. Your query will be a bit harder to read, but faster. This is left as a fun exercise for the reader :-). (And because I don't have testdata)

Comment: That's nonsense in general. Proof: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:953229842074

Comment: Don't use an article from 2001, with oracle version 8. That is not applicable for now, in 10 and 11 it is more performant

Comment: In sqlfiddle (without data) they use the same execution plan: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/661cd/1 versus http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/661cd/2

Answer (score 0):

Replace `WHERE t.order_no IN` with

```
JOIN
(subselect) sub ON t.order_no =sub.order_no
```

Replace the calls `AND date_appoint <= to_date('2014-04-17', 'yyyy-mm-dd')`
with `AND date_appoint <= :date_parameter` to avoid to_date() convert for each row.

Add indexes for the columns used in `WHERE`

Answer (score 0):

You make to many inner selects, you have to avoid this, use this instead:

```
SELECT t.order_no         ,
  user_assign             ,
  t.busi_code             ,
  t.inst_addr4 AS district,
  t.inst_addr3 AS estate  
 ,listagg(to_char(date_appoint,'yyyy-mm-dd'),',') within group(order by date_appoint asc) as "日期排序"
   FROM mtce_detail t
  WHERE exists
  (SELECT m.order_no,
      user_assign    ,
      COUNT(order_no) AS total
       FROM mtce_detail m
      WHERE date_appoint <= to_date('2014-04-17', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
        AND m.order_no = t.order_no
   GROUP BY order_no, user_assign
   HAVING count(order_no) > 2
  )
  group by t.order_no,t.user_assign,t.busi_code,t.inst_addr4,t.inst_addr3
```

Comment: what happened to `WHERE date_appoint = to_date('2014-04-17', 'yyyy-mm-dd')`?

Comment: This also selects mcte_details that don't have an occurrence on April 17, 2014.

Comment: He selects 3 times from mtce_detail so there is one clause that states date_appoint <= to_date('2014-04-17'....
This covers the inner select that says equals to.
If he really meant only equal to then he have to change the <= in =

Comment: @nightfox79syntax error with "having total>2", I think "having count(order_no)>2" is better, thank you all the same :)

Answer (score -1):

Just regarding this part:

```
SELECT m.order_no,
      user_assign    ,
      COUNT(order_no) AS total
       FROM mtce_detail m
      WHERE order_no IN
      (SELECT order_no
         FROM mtce_detail
        WHERE date_appoint = to_date('2014-04-17', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
      )
```

Why don't you just write it like this:

```
SELECT m.order_no,
      user_assign    ,
      COUNT(order_no) AS total
       FROM mtce_detail m
      WHERE date_appoint = to_date('2014-04-17', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Comment: oh,no. Some order_no have recorded both "2014-04-17" and other time.

Comment: so there are multiple rows for the same order_no?

Comment: Yep, I need to get these rows even though whose date_appoint not on "2014-04-17" but there is a row(at least) has the same order_no with it.